# Trying to migrate thread creation method from C to C++ does not work

Tags: c++, c, boost-thread

I have been looking for specific info to solve my problem but I think it's too much specific. I am working on a project which mixes c and c++ code in a way it's really confusing. At last I have had to take some C code and use it in a file which is compiled with C++. I though it will work with some changes but I have found one error that I can't solve for myself. It is about thread use.

I have declared two functions public, as I have received them, declared them in my header file `drviRIOAD_1D.h`, in my class `drviRIOAD_1D`:

```
void ai_pv_thread(void *p);
void aiDMA_thread(void *p);
```

then I have copied its code in my cpp file, drviRIOAD_1D.cpp:
(I will just include the part of code with errors)

```
void drviRIOAD_1D::aiDMA_thread(void *p){
 ai_pv_publish= (irio_dmathread_t*) malloc(sizeof(irio_dmathread_t)*irioPvt->DMATtoHOSTNCh[ai_dma_thread->id]);

    buffersize=irioPvt->DMATtoHOSTBlockNWords[ai_dma_thread->id];

    samples_per_channel=irioPvt->DMATtoHOSTBlockNWords[ai_dma_thread->id]*8; //Bytes per block
    samples_per_channel= samples_per_channel/irioPvt->DMATtoHOSTSampleSize[ai_dma_thread->id]; //Samples per block
    samples_per_channel= samples_per_channel/irioPvt->DMATtoHOSTNCh[ai_dma_thread->id];//Samples per channel per block

    // Ring Buffers for Waveforms PVs
    ai_dma_thread->IdRing= (void**) malloc(sizeof(epicsRingBytesId)*irioPvt->DMATtoHOSTNCh[ai_dma_thread->id]);
    // Creation and Launching of threads working as consumers for EPICS PVs publishing
    aux=(float**) malloc(sizeof(float*)*irioPvt->DMATtoHOSTNCh[ai_dma_thread->id]);
    for(i=0;i<irioPvt->DMATtoHOSTNCh[ai_dma_thread->id];i++){
        aux[i]=(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*samples_per_channel);
        if(ch_nelm[chIndex+i]!=0){
            ai_dma_thread->IdRing[i]=epicsRingBytesCreate(samples_per_channel*irioPvt->DMATtoHOSTSampleSize[ai_dma_thread->id]*4096);//!<Ring buffer to store manage the waveforms.
            ai_pv_publish[i].IdRing=&ai_dma_thread->IdRing[i];
            ai_pv_publish[i].dma_thread_name=(char *)malloc(40);
            sprintf(ai_pv_publish[i].dma_thread_name,"%sPVPublisher%02d",ai_dma_thread->dma_thread_name,i);
            ai_pv_publish[i].id=i; //channel identifier
            ai_pv_publish[i].dmanumber=ai_dma_thread->id; //dma identifier
            ai_pv_publish[i].threadends=0;
            ai_pv_publish[i].endAck=0;
            ai_pv_publish[i].asynPvt=ai_dma_thread->asynPvt;
            ai_pv_publish[i].dma_thread_id=epicsThreadCreate(ai_pv_publish[i].dma_thread_name,
                                epicsThreadPriorityHigh,epicsThreadGetStackSize(epicsThreadStackBig),
                                (EPICSTHREADFUNC)ai_pv_thread,  
                                (void *)&ai_pv_publish[i]); //Here occurs the error, it means that ai_pv_thread argument does not work properly

}
```

The last line gives me an error, the following:

> ../drviRIOAD_1D.cpp:1846: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)

And Here is the function `ai_pv_thread(void *p)`

```
void drviRIOAD_1D::ai_pv_thread(void *p){
//There is one thread per ringbuffer (per DMA channel)

irio_dmathread_t *pv_thread;
pv_thread=(irio_dmathread_t *)p;
irioDrv_t *irioPvt = &pv_thread->asynPvt->drvPvt;
float* pv_data;
int pv_nelem=4096,aux;
while (irio_threadsrun==0) {usleep(10000);}
aux=irioPvt->DMATtoHOSTChIndex[pv_thread->dmanumber]+pv_thread->id;

printf ("ch_nelm %d\n", ch_nelm[aux]);
pv_nelem=ch_nelm[aux];


pv_data = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*pv_nelem);
do{
    int NbytesDecimated;
    NbytesDecimated=epicsRingBytesUsedBytes(*pv_thread->IdRing);
    if(NbytesDecimated>=(sizeof(float)*pv_nelem))
    {
        if(epicsRingBytesIsFull(*pv_thread->IdRing)){
            //TODO: Error

        }

        epicsRingBytesGet(*pv_thread->IdRing,(char*)pv_data,sizeof(float)*pv_nelem);

        CallAIInsFloat32Array(pv_thread->asynPvt,CH,
                irioPvt->DMATtoHOSTChIndex[pv_thread->dmanumber]+pv_thread->id,pv_data,pv_nelem);
    }else{
        //@todo: fix this
        usleep(10000);
    }
}while (pv_thread->threadends==0);
free(pv_data);
free(pv_thread->dma_thread_name);
pv_thread->endAck=1;
}
```

What I can't understand is why this gives any error, as this code was working already. I think it's because the migration, but I'm not able to solve it.

In fact I have a near example with cpp and I have been working with it but with no results. In this case, they created the thread with a static callback which is outside the class that calls the function inside the class. The difference is that the argument of the function inside the class is `void`, `void callbackTask()` and in my case is `void ai_pv_thread(void *p)`.

The function that gives me problems is from an external API, which gives a C interface and C++ interface, maybe, is this also a problem? I think I'm not properly accesing my function ai_pv_thread, which is called without parameters, but in fact it needs a void *p. However I have tried some changes, for example add '::' (EPICSTHREADFUNC)::ai_pv_thread but in that case the compiler tells me error: '::ai_pv_thread' was not declared.

Can somebody explain me the difference between callbacks in C and C++ so I can explain this behaviour? What's the change I have to make to get it working? I can change function parameters such as static or the position of the fucntions, now they are public from class drviRIOAD_1D, but I can take them out.

This is the [link to this API](http://www.aps.anl.gov/epics/base/R3-14/12-docs/AppDevGuide/node21.html#SECTION0021142000000000000000) (Just to know the api for the function epicsThreadCreate):
`epicsThreadCreate` --> Create a new thread. The use made of the priority, and stackSize arguments is implementation dependent. Some implementations may ignore one or other of these, but for portability appropriate values should be given for both. The value passed as the stackSize parameter should be obtained by calling `epicsThreadGetStackSize`. The funptr argument specifies a function that implements the thread, and parm is the single argument passed to funptr. A thread terminates when funptr returns.

It's interface:

```
epicsThreadId epicsThreadCreate(const char *name,
unsigned int priority, unsigned int stackSize,
EPICSTHREADFUNC funptr,void *parm);
```

Comment: are you trying to use a member function as a thread start? because member functions that are not `static` have an implicit `this` parameter and will cause issues. Also I'm not seeing any use of `boost.thread` or `std::thread` anywhere here... you might also want to read up on [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Comment: Can you clarify why you say "And Here is the function ai_pv_publish(void *p)" but the code below is the function void drviRIOAD_1D::ai_pv_thread(void *p) ?

Comment: There's nothing in the compiler diagnostic that refers explicitly to ai_pv_thread. The compiler diagnostic could refer to any other part of that complicated function call and/or assignment. It's unlikely that anyone is going to read your entire API documentation and classes, in order to figure it out. You'll either have to reduce your example in size to something much smaller, or start by eliminating parts of the problematic statement, replacing them with appropriate stub values, until the compiler diagnostic goes away. Then, you will identify the real problem.

Comment: via @superpolock Just to confirm, you do have 'extern "c"' around your function spec, right?

Comment: I have to edit, ai_pv_publish(void *p)" it's wrong, I made a mistake, I meant "void ai_pv_thread(void *p)" as you can see in the code below the text.

Comment: The compiler error is related to this function, it points out that I'm not properly using this function. My problem is the following: knowing that this functions works in C, what change do I have to make to make it work in C++, as the function epicsThreadCreate needs the argument (EPICSTHREADFUNC)ai_pv_thread, but they way it's called does not work properly in C++ as the function ai_pv_thread needs void *p argument.

Comment: I have tried to take this function outside the class drviRIOAD_1D, but It does not work properly, and I don't know why it will change anything if it is static, or outside the class, the RAII link does not help me much, as I don't realize what has to do with this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RicardoHerrero you're coding C++ like you would C, it's also not clear where the error is occurring. I suggested RAII as a way of  managing your resources since you're using raw `malloc` in c++ which is a major code smell.

Comment: it's not a "major code smell", it's grounds for immediate termination of that employee except in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: As I have said I'm just trying to accomodate C code into a C++ file. That's why I still have malloc functions. I need to solve this problem: I'm calling a function inside another (inside epicsThreadCreate, function ai_pv_thread(void *p). This program worked in C, but it gives me an error in C++, which I don't really understand. I don't know how to do the same in C++. I suppose I have to change something of the function or the way I call it, but I don't know, so I need that someone who deals with C and C++ to tell me how to do it or at least why it is failing in C++. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `ai_pv_thread(void*)` is a member function then what you're doing is undefined behavior. Given the error you're getting I'm inclined to think so. To [start a thread using a member function you need to use a helper](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#memfnptr-vs-fnptr) like thus:

```
static void pv_thread_start(void* in)
{
    if(!in)
    {
        return;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<data_holder> holder(static_cast<data_holder*>(in));
    holder->obj->ai_pv_thread(holder->data);
}
```

alternatively you can use a static member function but the syntax for that is odd and I usually avoid it.

When creating the thread you'll probably need to pass in a POD object that has both `*this` and the data you need like thus:

```
struct data_holder{
    drviRIOAD_1D* obj;
    ai_pv_publish* data;
};
```

and at the point you create the thread:

```
auto data = std::make_unique<data_holder>({this, &ai_pv_publish[i]});
epicsThreadCreate(
    ai_pv_publish[i].dma_thread_name,
    epicsThreadPriorityHigh,
    epicsThreadGetStackSize(epicsThreadStackBig),
    // this cast is probably unncessary now
    static_cast<EPICSTHREADFUNC>(pv_thread_start),
    static_cast<void*>(data.release());
```

Comment: I had to start from scratch as It was everything mixed up between C and C++ code, so it became useless. Now I have reviewed my program from another point of view and it works.